# counts number of read/write happened to specific memory addresses on the main memory

Tags: performancecounter, perfmon, papi

I want to develop a tool that takes memory addresses as input and then counts number of read/write happened to those memory addresses on the main memory.

Is there any tool (like PAPI, Perfmon2) can help me to achieve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pin to trace memory accesses. Check out this link to the [Memory Reference Trace](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/49306/Pin/html/index.html#MAddressTrace)  section of the Pin manual.